# How to loop over an if condition in Bash?

Tags: bash

I want to know what conditions to put to start an if again so I want my program to loop until the answer is no:

```sh
function createFile {
  echo "Enter file name"
  read -r file
  mkdir /home/jeremy/MesFichiers/$file
  echo -n "do you want to create another file (y/n)?"
  read -r answer
  if [ "$answer" != "$answer#[Yy]]}" ];
    echo "enter file name"
    read -r file
    mkdir /home/jeremy/MesFichiers/$file
  # (conditions to restart the if)
  else
    echo "Thanks"
  fi
}
```

Comment: See the `while` loop [for example](https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/bash-while-loop/).

Comment: Please accept the answer you think the best as correct by clicking on the gray check mark ✔️ next to the answer and turn it green ✅. This will help others.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest using a *while loop*, with a *conditional break* ex.

```
#!/bin/bash

while :
do
  read -r -p "Enter file name: " file
  mkdir "/home/jeremy/MesFichiers/$file"

  read -r -p "do you want to create another file (y/n)? " answer
  case $answer in
    [Yy]*)
      continue
    ;;
    *)
      echo "Thanks"
      break
    ;;
  esac
done
```

Note that if you decide to use an `if ... then` construct in place of the `case` statement, the syntax of the test operator is very specific about whitespace i.e. `if [ string1 = string2 ]`

Comment: thank you its works really well

Answer (score 1):

Here is another version doing the same thing as [steeldriver's answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1317790/how-to-restart-a-if-in-bash/1317792#1317792) with conditional while loop. This makes the code shorter:

```
#!/bin/bash

while [[ ${answer:=y} = [Yy] ]]          # sets default to y. [Yy] accepts both Y or y
do
  read -r -p "Enter file name: " file  
  mkdir "/home/jeremy/MesFichiers/$file"
  read -r -p "do you want to create another file (y/n)? " answer
done
```

Hope this helps

Comment: think you can even do `[[ ${answer=y} = [Yy] ]]` and skip `answer=y`, will shave one more line.

Comment: minor note: probably, one would typically usually prefer  `[[ ${answer:=y} = [Yy] ]] `, vs just `${answer=y}`, the latter which I actually never use, as it only works if `answer` is `unset`, vs eg explicitly set to no value / initialized to an empty value (for the same reason, I never use any of the default value parameter expansions that omit the colon) https://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/pe#assign_a_default_value (but in any case, assigning a default value might still be safest to avoid weird results in case `answer` is set in the env)

Comment: Thanks @michael I have edited my answer.

Comment: Thanks @bac0n for the suggestion. I learned a lot from your comments.

Answer (score 0):

You could also make use of `trap` to intercept a shell signal. Starting `read` inside a subshell makes sure `trap` executes the code inside the loop and not on the script itself.

```bsh
#!/bin/bash

trap \
'printf \\n%s\\n "ctrl + c ..."; break' SIGINT

a=${1:-$HOME/MesFichiers}
while :; do
    ( \
        read -r -p \
        "Create a directory in '$a' (ctrl + c to abort): " && mkdir "$a/$REPLY" \
    )
done

trap - SIGINT # Reset specified signal.

echo "Rest of the code!"
```